# native Domino links and XPages

Tags: url, xpages

Users open documents by links in old format `http://server/db.nsf/VIEW_UNID/DOC_UNID`. The form has property set to open XPage instead.

Origin of these links is email notification generated by "universal agent". It simply sends link to document. It does not know, what form is associated with what XPage, therefore it generates universal links instead of "/page.xsp&documentId=...".

**The problem**: relative links computed at client do not work - `< a href = "/page.xsp?params">` should be more effective - no roundtrip and easy to compute at page load. They evaluate to `http://server/db.nsf/0/page.xsp?params`, what ends with Error 404, naturaly.

XPage contains "help" section, what is another document with RT field containing text, images and links. And relative links in that RT field work when XPage is opened from another XPage - view (/page.xsp), but fail when redirected from notification link (/0/UNID).

**Question**: How to effectively reset browser's address bar to extended XPages format `http://server/db.nsf/page.xsp?documentId=DOC_UNID` after opening redirected documents/views by old fashioned URLs?

Comment: Why is your agent not creating links with *$$OpenDominoDocument.xsp* instead? Btw.: The link */page.xsp&params* cannot work. Instead it should be */page.xsp?params*.

Comment: @SvenHasselbach: not every application is based on XPages. and that btw: you're right, I just typed it here as example...

Comment: Please clarify your question and fix the urls in your question ("&" vs. "?").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main problem is in discrepancy of relative links on server side (evaluated in SSJS) and client side (evaluated by browser). I have solved my problem by simple redirect in case document is open by old fashioned link.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
        <xp:eventHandler event="onClientLoad" submit="false">
            <xp:this.script><![CDATA[var url = "#{javascript:context.getUrl()}";
    var l = window.location;
    if (url != l) {
        window.location.replace(url);
    }
    ]]></xp:this.script>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:view>
```

Simply said, if open URL differs from internal URL (as resolved by XSP engine), browser redirects to correct URL. This solved many problems we had with inline images (image resource) and attachments.

Answer (score 0):

Try "./page.xsp&params" or ../ if you want to go back to the root - I have noticed IBM do this in their coding as well. Hope this helps.

Comment: users can open page with correct link, so your advice would evaluate to http://server/page.xsp or http://server/path/page.xsp...

Comment: Maybe I mis-understood your question, is it possible to provide a sample code or clarify further what you mean by "opening redirected documents/views by old fashioned URLs"? Are they generated using LS code or by the end user in a notes document or formula language etc? What does relative links computed at client do not work refer to,  please clarify? Are these links computed on a document by end user or are they computed in forms?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set pageBaseUrl property in your XPages? This would help to repair the relativ links:

```
<xp:this.pageBaseUrl>
   <xp:baseUrl>
      <xp:this.href><![CDATA[#{javascript:"http://stackoverflow.com/"}]]></xp:this.href>
   </xp:baseUrl>
</xp:this.pageBaseUrl>
```

Another idea is to do a redirect in *beforePageLoad*-event in the XPage if the URL is in old fashioned style.

Comment: Yes, this is what I have in mind in my question. I think just site url won't work, tho. What would you suggest to put inside baseUrl property to preserve url parameters and anchors, if any?

Comment: I don't understand what you exactly want to realize: Why is it required for the relativ links that you add the original URL parameters? How does such a link look like? Can you give an example?