# How to link to an xpage in email?

Tags: xpages, lotusscript, xpinc

In lotusscript I usually do the following to create a simple email which contains a link that points to a notes database/view. Is there any way I can modify the link(appenddoclink) so that it opens an xpage? Say my xpage name is "Staff_Page".

```
Dim maildoc As NotesDocument, rtitem As NotesRichTextItem
Set maildoc=New NotesDocument(db)
maildoc.subject="Email Address(s) For Your Approval"
Set rtitem=New NotesRichTextItem(maildoc, "Body")
Call rtitem.Appendtext("Dear John,")
Call rtitem.Addnewline(2)
Call rtitem.Appenddoclink(db, "", "Click to open the XPage.")           
Call maildoc.Send(False, "john@mail.com")
```

I've looked at the XPages URL Cheat Sheet but those are not lotusscript. I'm doing XPiNC with some lotusscript agent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easiest one is to specify in your Form properties "open xpage instead" 
Second option is to specify a URL link pointing to it with the href=notes://server/.... 
You might be better off using mime mail (snippets for that on OpenNTF) since you have easier formatting options

Comment: this is the way to do it, but beware of problems, if such document/form is opened by native Domino URL format in browser - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10802986/native-domino-links-and-xpages

Comment: Frantisek is right. So when you do MIME messages, you want to use the ...nsf/myPages.xsp&unid... format