# xe:breadCrumb Use Without Tree Nodes?

Tags: xpages

I have an XPages app with a page > sub-page structure that is defined by URL parameters prior to our company's adoption of Domino 8.5.3 UP1. Now that we do have UP1, I've been eyeing up the xe:breadCrumbs control with a little bit of envy. Not being familiar with xe:pageTreeNodes (which I know at least exist thanks to my copy of XPages Extension Library), I figured I'd "phone a friend". I couldn't find much on the topic. My question is two-fold:

1. How *should* one implement page tree structure to use properly with the xe:breadCrumbs control?
2. With my current setup (root page being standard page parameter, sub-page being a second, custom parameter), how easily can I use my setup with xe:breadCrumbs?

At some point, I'm more than willing to cut my losses and just build out a quasi-breadcrumbs element with some computed xp:link controls in a div. Since the opportunity arose, I figured I would check and see if there were some better options. I know this is a little vague, but I think the idea is communicated here.

[Edit:]
I should probably ask if this is something more directly and exclusively used with the xe:navigator. If that's the case, then I may be a little more sad, but a bit less confused.
[/Edit]

Comment: Not sure what is your problem, exactly. You can build any content with tree objects: they can be fed from your bean (suggested), or compositeData or repeat (if treated as object array).

Comment: So, I've got page structure that was built without a bean, without much (actually anything) in the way of compositeData at the root page level. 

Using an xp:callback for the main content, tied to "page" param. So I guess my problem is that there isn't any current bean (which I've not dealt with yet) and I'm more at the point of "how the heck do I implement it?"

@FrantisekKossuth do you know of any good examples/demo db where I could see this in action? That might help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tree nodes are fine. Here is small example. Prerequisites:

- all documents are in the same database. Not a big issue, just update href params accordingly.
- Document contains fields with ID and Label (subject, title) of parent documents (all levels)
- There is view "id" containing only one column sorted by document's id to open it (Domino syntax) - see also: [native Domino links and XPages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10802986/native-domino-links-and-xpages/11537085#11537085)
- dds is curent document's datasource
- ddsParent is parent document's datasource

  ```
  <xe:breadCrumbs id="breadCrumbs1">

  <xe:this.treeNodes>

      <xe:basicLeafNode label="Top document: ${dds.fld_TopLabel}">
          href="/id/${dds.fld_TopID}">
      </xe:basicLeafNode>
      <xe:basicLeafNode label="Sub1: ${ddsParent.fld_Label}">
          <xe:this.href><![CDATA[#{javascript:"/0/" + ddsPonuka.getDocument().getUniversalID()}]]></xe:this.href>
      </xe:basicLeafNode>
      <xe:basicLeafNode label="Current level: ${dds.fld_Label}">
      </xe:basicLeafNode>
  </xe:this.treeNodes>
  ```

You have to alter this for every XPage. Sure, you can make it a custom control with parameters, but you will end up with custom control on every XPage fed by parameters roughly in the same structure.

The best option is to make managed bean configurable in some sort and returning ExtLib tree objects. Then your source will be reduced to:

```
<xe:beanTreeNode nodeBean="my.bean.Class"></xe:beanTreeNode>
```

Best example is XPagesExt.nsf bundled with ExtLib distributions.

Comment: I think that clears it up a bit. I see why you recommend the bean approach, pushing all the nav logic through it for less "thinking" at the page level. I think for what I have now, I'm not set up for an easy implementation without a bit of extra work, so I'll probably come back to this on my next project and see where it takes me.  
In the meantime I'll probably just _cheat_ and make a custom control containing a series of computed fields which mimic the look and feel of xe:breadCrumbs, but using my own computation via shared script off of the params.